# Symfony 3 get object data in EntityType form field

Tags: php, symfony, twig, entity, symfony-forms

I've got the Form with two EntityType fields

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
     $builder
        ->add('supplier', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'         => 'AppBundle:Supplier',
            'choice_label'  => 'pubName',
            'label'         => false,
            'expanded'      => true
        ))
        ->add('payment', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'         => 'AppBundle:Payment',
            'choice_label'  => 'pubName',
            'label'         => false,
            'expanded'      => true
        ));
}
```

And I want to get fields of passed objects in Twig template, so I could get the name, or description of every entity to customize my form view. How can I achieve that in the way?

Comment: There appear to be no options to define what property of the entities you want to display. One would expect, for example, a `'choices' => $entity->getProperties()` or `'query_builder' => ...`.

Comment: Can you please explain your question by providing some twig sample. Its not mandatory that it's working sample but at-least will give some idea of what you are trying to achieve? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom type with EntityType as parent for both of your entities.

Take a look at this documentation page: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/create_form_type_extension.html

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current data of your form via `form.vars.value`:

```
{{ form.vars.value.supplier }} {# Your Supplier object #}
{{ form.vars.value.payment }} {# Your Payment object #}
```

**Reference: [How to Control the Rendering of a Form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/rendering.html)**